# How to respond to an HTTP request using Python

Tags: python, ios, webserver, download

I am trying to write an iPhone application that uses a Python server. The iPhone application will send an HTTP request to the server, which should then respond by sending back a file that is on the server. What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why specifically a Python server if all it does is send back a file? Why not `nginx` or Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a basic web framework for coding up the page(s) that will return the content. You could use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for example, which is lightweight and you can write the Python code that it needs to do.

Comment: Flask seems to be the best match for my application. do you know how to send a file using Flask? Thanks. I tried return open(myfile) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a basic web framework, such as Flask, or use the [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) library for python.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

See http://www.garyrobinson.net/2004/03/one_line_python.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're literally just serving content (ie, not doing any calculations or look-ups), then use the nginx webserver to serve it based on URL.